# Scala DSL: How to omit parentheses from apply call?

Tags: scala, dsl

I wrote a small library for units of measure (yes, I could use squants for this, but I need some features squants does not provide). My unit class is `UnitOfMeasure` and a quantity, i.e., a number and a unit, is `Quantity`.

Suppose I defined `m` as a `UnitOfMeasure`, I want to write something like:

```
val q = 3.0 m
```

I created a class `QuantityWrapper` in a package object like so:

```
implicit class QuantityWrapper[T](value: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]) {

  def apply(unit: UnitOfMeasure[T]): Quantity[T] =
    Quantity(value, unit)
}
```

So I can now do:

```
val q = 3.0(m)
```

because the 3.0 is implicitly converted to a `QuantityWrapper[Double]` and `m` is already defined as `UnitOfMeasure[Double]`.

But I want to be able to omit the parentheses. Is this possible without defining methods in `QuantityWrapper` for every unit I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible without defining methods in `QuantityWrapper` for every unit I have?

No. Whatever you do, `3.0 m` will always be parsed as `(3.0).m`, so there must exist a method `m` on `Double` (possibly through an implicit conversion).

Comment: OK, I will then define the most common units as methods and go with the parenthesized version for the others.